# Checking for null variable in Workflow 4.0 transition condition

Tags: .net, vb.net, workflow-foundation

I'm implementing a State Machine in WF 4.0. In some transitions, I have added a condition where I check that some variables have the expected values. The variables are enums and booleans, and everything is fine.

However, now I tried to evaluate when a property is null. I have and argument in my workflow, let's say, *'MyArgument'*. In a transition, I try to put a condition like *'MyArgument.MyProperty = Nothing*'. I never developed in VB.NET, I don't know if I'm missing something here...

VS2010 gives the following error: "*Error 4 Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "MyArg.MyProp = Nothing".
Operator '=' is not defined for types 'XXXX' and 'XXXX'*

The type names are exactly the same, and I have debugged VS2010 to ensure that my assembly is not loaded from 2 different locations.

Has somebody faced the same problem? Is there any thing I'm missing? How can I check if the property is null or not?

BTW, I'm using VS2010 SP 1, with .NET Platform Update 1 installed, on W7 64 bits.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ok, after writing the question, I started to forget about multiple assemblies loaded, etc... and looked for more stupid problems... MyArg.MyProperty Is Nothing works fine ... :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this answers your question since my situation is, I think, different than yours. And I apologise if this is unnecessarily repeating things you are already well-versed in.

I have a workflow-scoped variable that I'll call "WorkflowXvariable". I have a custom activity called "CustomActivity". To interact with WorkflowXvariable within CustomActivity's code, I have to do two things first:
1) Create a property in the CustomActivity class that I'll use for referencing WorkflowX. I'll call this "ActivityXproperty".
2) In the visual designer, in the property grid for an instance of CustomActivity, I set ActivityXProperty to WorkflowXVariable.

WorkflowXvariable may be null. In CustomActivity's code I can test for this:

if (ActivityXproperty == null)
  return;

I came across your post because I'd like to be able to check if ActivityXproperty was not set to WorkflowXvariable as it should have been -- whether its "expression" is nothing. I have not determined a way to do this, such as checking whether Activity.Expression is null.

Whether because the expression for ActivityXproperty was not set to anything, or because WorkflowXvariable is null, all I can test for is whether or not ActivityXproperty is null.

Answer (score 0):

I am solving similar problem with checking if the variable is null.
My soulution is:

1. Declare extra local variable:

   < Sequence.Variables
    Variable x:TypeArguments="x:Boolean" Default="False" Name="MyBooleanProperty" />
   < /Sequence.Variables>
2. Check if MyVariable (which is array of string) is not null:

   < mtbwe:IsNotNull x:TypeArguments="s:String[]" sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="IsNotNull`1_1" Result="MyBooleanProperty]" Value="[MyVariable]" />
3. Using MyBooleanProperty in if condition:

   < If Condition="[MyBooleanProperty AndAlso MyVariable.Count > 0]" DisplayName="If MyVariable is not empty" sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="If_35">
4. mtbwe is a reference to WF Expressions library:

   < xmlns:mtbwe="clr-namespace:Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Expressions;assembly=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow">